# Rewrite rule needed for cms php melody urls rebuilding

Tags: mysql, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, content-management-system, php-5.3

I have recently upgraded my website cms from older version to new one, 
Everything was fine except the old video urls are built on that format:

```
www.example.com/artist_name/videoUrl_ID.html
```

the artist name field is removed from database to fit new database architecture..
and to avoid that problem, i need to rewrite those urls to:

```
www.example.com/videoUrl_ID.html
```

which means removing this artist_name field from the urls(old urls published on the web)

**{$video_data.uniq_id}**: code i use to call video id.
Expaple:

```
http://www.example.com/CNN_News/news-march-30-2016_3a7017eff.html
```

Must be changed to:

```
http://www.example.com/news-march-30-2016_3a7017eff.html
```

Comment: Sorry it is unclear that the problem is.

Comment: Ok i have edited question to be clear enough.thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/[\w-]+/([\w-]+\.html)$ /$1
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhava but the  /CNN_News/ is a dynamic field that changes from url to another, so this will fix only one url ..what do you think?

Comment: I suggest either to remove everything before the first and the second slash or to rewrite all urls of the first style( /artist_name/url_we_want_to_keep) to display only the second part which is exactly the {$video_data.uniq_id} which is the dynamic video link code in the new version of cms(php melody)